# Change array order at any given index

Tags: javascript

Given the following array

```
const arr = [13, 6075, 51]
```

I would like to modify the above array in this way:

- be able to get 'n' elements before a certain index,
- remove these elements
- add them to the end of the same array.

```
// result if the selected index was `1`:
[6075, 51, 13]

// result if the selected index was `2`:
[51, 13, 6075]
```

I have been able to do this with 'slice' but on a *copy* of the array, not on the array I'd like to modify itself.

Comment: please add your try. what goes wrong?

Comment: I do it on a *copy* (creating a new array). I would like to do this do the array itself now.

Comment: you didn't say if the elements to be added at the end should follow a rule. 
bc if there is no rule to how these elements should be organized 
you can simply, use a variable to swap values x = arr[0]; arr[0] = arr[n]; arr[n] = x;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to do the removal via `splice`, which will give you an array of what was removed, then use `push` to add those things back at the end:

```
function swap(arr, index) {
    const removed = arr.splice(0, index);
    arr.push(...removed);
    return arr; // Just for chaining, the array is modified in place
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const arr = [13, 6075, 51];

function swap(arr, index) {
    const removed = arr.splice(0, index);
    arr.push(...removed);
    return arr;
}

console.log(swap([13, 6075, 51], 1));
console.log(swap([13, 6075, 51], 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

### Simple Answer

The simplest solution is to use the `shift` and `push` operators.

- `shift` will remove an element from the start of an array
- `push` will add an element to the end of an array

If you perform these two operations in sequence then it will take one element from the start and put it on the end, like so:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var element = arr.shift();
arr.push(element);
console.log(arr); // [2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Using a `for` loop you can do this "N" times:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var element = arr.shift();
    arr.push(element);
}
```

### More Efficient Answer

If you're not constrained by memory, you can just operate on a copy of the array (as you said you've done) and then overwrite the original:

```
var removedElements = arr.splice(0, n);
arr = arr.concat(removedElements);
```

### More Efficient In-Place Answer

You can push multiple elements at once using `Array.prototype.push.apply()` like so:

```
var removedElements = arr.splice(0, n);
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, removedElements);
```

This is one of the "better" answers, but requires understanding of prototypes - so I saved it for last.

### ES6 Answer

Using modern JavaScript notation you can actually perform `Array.prototype.push.apply` without any ugliness:

```
var removedElements = arr.splice(0, n);
ar.push(...removedElements);
```

The above can be turned into a one-liner:

```
arr.push(...arr.splice(0, n));
```

### Functional Programming Answer

The operation you're performing is called a "rotation" on the array. Sometimes also referred to as "cycling". You may be able to find a functional programming library that will give you a rotate method, allowing code like:

```
arr.rotate(n);
```

I took a quick look and a function like this was requested in Lodash, but it was rejected and never implemented: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2173

Comment: Your best answer is a bit outdated with modern versions of JavaScirpt

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the tip. I updated with an "ES6 Answer" and threw in a "Functional Programming Answer" just to introduce the concept of advanced array operations

Answer (score 1):

You could change the length of the array and take [`Array#copyWithin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin) for moving values.

At the end change the length back.

```js
function move(array, index) {
    const l = array.length;
    array.length += index;
    array.copyWithin(l, 0, index);
    array.copyWithin(0, index, index + l);
    array.length = l;
}

const array = [13, 6075, 51];


move(array, 1);
console.log(...array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.slice` two get the two parts, and `.concat` to return the result:

```js
const swapPartsAtIndex = (arr=[], index=-1) => {
  if(index <= 0 || index >= arr.length) return arr;
  return arr.slice(index,arr.length).concat(arr.slice(0,index));
}

let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
arr = swapPartsAtIndex(arr, 3);
console.log(...arr);

arr = swapPartsAtIndex([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 3);
console.log(...arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myArray = [13, 6075, 51, 44, 67, 78]


function shiftArrayEntries(arr, index) {
   const shiftedEntries = arr.splice(0, index)
   
   return arr.concat(shiftedEntries)
}

console.log(shiftArrayEntries(myArray, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
const shiftArray = (array, idx) => array.concat(array.splice(0, idx));

shiftArray([13, 6075, 51], 1) //[6075, 51, 13]
shiftArray([13, 6075, 51], 2) //[51, 13, 6075]
```